# how to send a custom notification to my google home mini using the cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-home

I have node js app built on Firebase with firebase cloud function and I want to send a custom notification to my Google Home Mini like system alerts.

`example: Hello. You have a new user registered on your website`

How I can do that with cloud function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) with Actions on Google are not currently supported on Smart Speakers.